# Play! framework's .withLang(...) not taking effect immediately

Tags: scala, internationalization, playframework-2.0

I want to allow the user of my web application to change the current language (for [i18n](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaI18N) purposes). This is done by appending the language code to the URL as a HTTP GET parameter (e.g. `/somePage?lang=en`). The language code is then resolved in the correspionding controller method and set via `.withLang(lang)`.

I am using [action composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaActionsComposition) to provide this functionality and avoid boilerplate code:

```
def withLang(f: => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Action { implicit request =>
  request.getQueryString("lang").flatMap(Lang.get(_)) match {
    case Some(lang) => f(request).withLang(lang)
    case None       => f(request)
  }
}
```

The composition can then be used as follows:

```
def somePage = withLang { implicit request =>
  //do some stuff
  Ok(views.html.somePage())
}
```

This solution works fine. If I call `/somePage?lang=en`, the language of the web application is permanently switched to english. However, this only applies to subsequent pages. The current page is still served in the old language:

1. call `/somePage1`: served in default language
2. call `/somePage2?lang=en`: still served in default language
3. call `/somePage3`: served in english

Why is the language change not taking effect immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved it by using a `Redirect` instead of rendering the page directly:

```
def withLang(f: => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Action { implicit request =>
  val referrer = request.headers.get(REFERER).getOrElse("/")
  request.getQueryString("lang").flatMap(Lang.get(_)) match {
    case Some(lang) => Redirect(referrer).withLang(lang)
    case None       => f(request)
  }
}
```

Comment: The same goes for the Flash cookie.